# How to match a word to a number in Stata?

Tags: stata

I have a list of 2505000 data points (in Data Editor) (although the numbers within are between 1-6680 - each number repeats itself 375 times, so that's why I get 250500 fields in this particular column labeled "id").

What I need is to match a word to each of the numbers - ideally batches of numbers: e.g., "cats" to numbers 1,2,56,45,67,55 and "dogs" to 3,59,46,68,11 and then other phrases to other numbers (numbers between 1-6680).

These words should be in a new column (whatever name) and simply correspond with the numbers in column "id".

Can anyone advise on how to do it? Thanks

**Clarification:**

In my data editor, data is listed in column one ("id"):

[image]

The data goes all the way down to field 2505000:

[image]

The important thing to note, however, is that the data between the fields 1 and 2505000 is limited to numbers (in "id" column) from 1 to 6680. Each number appears there 375 times - i.e. 375*6680=2505000.

Now, what I need is to create a new variable where words correspond to specific numbers in the "id" variable:

[image]

dog equals 3138, 3076, 2851

cat equals 1579, 1449

auto 1810, 2351, 353

...and so on for other words and number combinations.

Comment: I can't follow what is meant here. Can you give a very small fake example with just a few numbers and names making precise how the data are held in Stata?

Comment: I have added some clarification - thanks Nick

Comment: Thanks for trying. Someone else may understand this, but I am still missing what you want.

Comment: I need to create a new variable in which I match words to specific numbers in column "id" dog would be matched to 3138, 3076, 2851, while other words to other numbers. Sorry I can't think of making this request easier - I would have done it in Excel but I simply have too many data points and hence I'm in Stata. It's like a lookup in a way, find a number in column "id" and place a specific word next to every instance of this number in the adjacent column.

Comment: But where does the matching come from?

Comment: I was expecting something that I could write into a command window e.g. if variable data point = number, number, number, number, number...,number, then "dog" - a sort of multi-level if statement? Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you seek the `inlist()` function.